# import csv file to oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I am trying to import data from txt file to table. The TXT file is having 5 records.
'ext.txt' is my file .'IMPORT' is a directory.

Records are

```
7499,ALLEN,SALESMAN,30
7521,WARD,SALESMAN,30
7566,JONES,MANAGER,20
7654,MARTIN,SALESMAN,30
```

I tried below query but its only inserts 3rd record to the external table.

Can anyone provide me the reason for this ans solution for insert all rows.

```
create table ext_tab (
  empno  CHAR(4),
  ename  CHAR(20),
  job1    CHAR(20),
  deptno CHAR(2)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY IMPORT
ACCESS PARAMETERS (
  RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
  BADFILE IMPORT:'test.bad' 
  LOGFILE IMPORT:'test.log' 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (
    empno char(4) ,   
    ename char(4), 
    job1 CHAR(20),
    deptno CHAR(2)
   )
)
LOCATION (import:'ext.txt')
)
PARALLEL 5
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Comment: change `ename char(4),` to `ename char(20),` in your import specification. BTW, you could check the test.bad file for errors before posting here

Comment: Down voted for asking the same question twice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173037/insert-data-from-csv-file-to-sql-table

Comment: Why vote down both questions?  Just close the worst one (in this case the other once because there is no test data or working code).

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your given test data

```
CREATE TABLE ext_tab (
  empno  VARCHAR(4),
  ename  VARCHAR(20),
  job1   VARCHAR(20),
  deptno VARCHAR(2)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY import
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  )
LOCATION ('ext.txt')
);
```

providing that you have set up the `import` directory correctly.

Tested on 11.2.0.4

As for the reason it was given in the comments above.  Always check the `.bad` and `.log` files first (created in the directory you put the file in).  These are very helpful at telling you why rows are rejected.

I expect you have errors like this in the log:-

```
KUP-04021: field formatting error for field ENAME                 
KUP-04026: field too long for datatype                            
KUP-04101: record 1 rejected in file /import_dir/ext.txt    
KUP-04021: field formatting error for field ENAME                 
KUP-04026: field too long for datatype                            
KUP-04101: record 3 rejected in file /import_dir/ext.txt    
KUP-04021: field formatting error for field ENAME                 
KUP-04026: field too long for datatype                            
KUP-04101: record 4 rejected in file /import_dir/ext.txt
```

and that only WARD was imported because only his name fits into `CHAR(4)`.